# Capitalisation of Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn

Tags: bug, status-completed, facebook, spelling, twitter

At the bottom of [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered):

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   twitter, facebook, or linkedin.

This is a real full sentence, so should those names be capitalised properly like this?

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   Twitter, Facebook, or LinkedIn.

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978617):

[image]

Also, I noticed when you add an answer, the names are capitalised properly: "share your answer on Facebook Twitter LinkedIn".

Comment: Or maybe should be E-Mail..

Comment: No, it should stay as email.

Comment: Also, I just noticed when you add an answer, the names are capitalised properly: "share your answer on  Facebook  Twitter  LinkedIn".

Comment: Also, when you edit your profile, there's a whole load of these lowercase names in the unfilled text boxes, and also Linkedin should be LinkedIn.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes.

If I was editing a question I would capitalize them properly (though I wouldn't edit a question just for that).

We should have the same standards for our messages as we would for our edits.

Comment: Great! So when is it fixed? :)

Comment: [6-8 weeks.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Answer (score 6):

Yes... No... Maybe. Chicken???

Go to those web sites. LinkedIn's<sup>TM</sup> is Linked`in`. Twitter is `twitter`. Facebook is `facebook`. While the common capitalizations make sense, it is hard to say that these don't entirely not make sense too (triple-negative is purposeful there). It becomes even harder as Google+ will undoubtedly be added, and `Google` in addition to being the all-powerful web corporation, is, along with Facebook, and Twitter, are all, at least in informal English, verbs.

Immediately, I can find one example of [another source](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=3e0_1247617508) which is following the same mentality which drove the lack of capitalization.

Personal opinion? Always use as proper of a form as possible -- LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter. But I also believe that it is a tragic misfortune that people exclude semi-colons from SMS and IM's.

Comment: +1, for good points on actual site usage.

Comment: I notice that all the copyright notices on those sites are capitalized: LinkedIn, Facebook and Twitter.  What a conundrum.

Comment: @Lance +1 to you because I agree. High standards for language!

Comment: I don't really understand what semicolons have to do with this problem. I've had no trouble using semicolons in SMS...

Comment: @Cody It is a matter of standards -- informal English is becoming less and less proper.

Comment: I disagree, your example is about the logos. My question is about plaintext. Those sites capitalise their names when using plaintext. Also verbs have nothing to do with it, this usage is nouns.

Comment: @Hugo I agree that they should be capitalized in accord with their "print names", but I will also state that there is justification for the alternate argument. That said, I will also state that justification is not the strongest, but I cannot deny that it exists.

Comment: Big talk coming from a guy whose name is entirely in lowercase (also, +1).

Comment: @Justin My name isn't lowercase, my username is. And it is on gmail, and on my company website, and on... I'll say it is my "brand name", and then royally confuse the situation. ;-)

Comment: @cwallenpoole Surely you mean Gmail not gmail (according to both logo and plaintext) :)

Comment: @Hugo Hey, don't call me on my hypocrisy.

Answer (score 6):

This is a change that should be made, looking at Twitter's (just using Twitter as an example) "[Guidelines for Use of the Twitter Trademark](http://support.twitter.com/entries/77641)" it clearly states:

> On the web: Use the phrase "Follow me/us on Twitter" with the word
>   "Twitter" spelled out

Clearly, Facebook and LinkedIn have similar policies somewhere, but Twitter's was most easily available.

Further down its clearly written:

> `Please remember to capitalize the T in Twitter and Tweet!`

Comment: For those who like such guidelines: [all about +1'ing](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1207011&answer=1237207&rd=1) (I refuse to use an uppercase T in "tweet".)

Answer (score 6):

As kd7 found the guidelines for Twitter, I thought I hunt down the others.

[Facebook guidelines:](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/index.php)

> 5.  When referenced in text, Facebook should be capitalized.

[Twitter](http://support.twitter.com/entries/77641) (as kd7 already linked us to):

> Please remember to capitalize the T in Twitter and Tweet!

[LinkedIn:](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/branding-guidelines)

LinkedIn isn't very clear on this. I can't find anything specifically about capitalizing it. Although, it looks like they would like something like: `LinkedIn® professional networking services` as a text link but `LinkedIn®` should be sufficient.

Comment: Good stuff. Although I would drop the unsightly ® like they do in plain text: http://press.linkedin.com/about

Answer (score 5):

Well, LinkedIn isn't there any longer, but the capitalization on Facebook and Twitter should be correct after the next build, matching the other places they're used in the site.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This time [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) = 6-8 months :)