# Could the words in the "Title" box when one is asking a question be properly capitalized?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have proper casing in the question title watermark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118059/could-we-have-proper-casing-in-the-question-title-watermark)

I requested [on Meta EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/as-a-site-about-elu-should-we-maintain-correct-grammar-punctuation-etc-thro) that the words in the Title box be capitalized properly, seeing as how we are a site that advocates the proper use of capitalization in writing. Additionally, the [people over at Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/proposed-capitalisation-fix) want the word *Christianity* capitalized. Could the words in the Title box please be capitalized across the network, or at the very least, on the two aforementioned sites?

Image of problem:
[image]

Comment: Next thing you'll want is for the links at the top of the page (review, chat, meta, etc) to be proper cased as well... when will the insanity end?

Comment: It's a (awesome) style, not bad grammar.

Comment: @M.Babcock My major issue is that the title box contains a complete sentence and complete sentences should start with capitals. As well, English should be capitalized.

Comment: Perhaps, though there are plenty of fonts that include only lowercase letters (even in place of uppercase ones). Would you argue that they're incorrect as well?

Comment: @M.Babcock I would say that according to the rules of the English language, sentences should start with capital letters and proper nouns should be capitalized. So yes, I would say that their style is incorrect.

Comment: Language structure and format is often compromised for style and taste (hence the need for slang). I fix grammar in posts all day on SO possibly caused by the same _bug_, but I don't really see a point in fixing it (granted I'm on SO where half of the users are non-native English speakers and most of the rest could care less). Do you want it to also correct the grammar of the question? How far does this really go?

Comment: @M.Babcock I'm not trying to be an extremist. All I'm asking for at the current time is the capitalization of a few little words in a title bar. I do not see the need to capitalize the review | chat | etc. links because they are not full sentences. I think FAQ should be capitalized, of course, because it is an initialism.

Comment: Oh no... you can't mess with my faq! What will happen to all of my sock puppet scripts that are taught to ignore it? Seriously though, I could care less. I just ask that it is _not_ changed on SO, we have enough users confused by the language without adding additional glyphs that they aren't familiar with yet.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks, didn't find that while searching. I voted to close.

Comment: I already added a comment to that other feature request too, but maybe you want to add your reasoning as an answer? (That would also bump that question onto the front page again...)